# django dynamic model object in query api

Tags: django, model, geodjango

I have 5 model class with geometric data and other different parameters.  In a search I need to query the data in all these five model classes based on the user selection i.e. dynamically change model class in query.   For that in django 1.4 I used `models.__dict__[layer]` and based on the select the layer field  varies.  But now I am working in django 1.11 and this is not working.
In django 1.4 I used,

```
 data =  models.__dict__[layer].objects.filter(name__icontains=keyWd).values('name').order_by('name')
```

In django 1.11, I tried the same but failed.

what is the best method for the solution.

Comment: can you share some codes on what you have tried? also the previous implementations from django 1.4?

Comment: In django 1.4, data =  models.__dict__[layer].objects.filter(name__icontains=keyWd).values('name').order_by('name')    No I tried the same but failed.

Comment: please add that to your question and also add the model structure please